# How to get content of selected DataGrid cell when SelectionUnit=Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridcell

I want to get the value of the cell the user is selecting like so:

[image]

However it's turning out to be more challenging than I thought it would be.

I've been digging around on the contents of these:

```
DataGridCellInfo currentCell = MyDataGrid.CurrentCell;
DataGridCellInfo selectedCell = MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[0];

// object selectedItems = MyDataGrid.SelectedItems[0]; throws index out of range error

object selectedValue = MyDataGrid.SelectedValue; // null
object selectedItem = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem; // null
```

But I can't find the simple text in any of these. Does anyone know where to get the value "MEH"? Preferably from a `DataGridCellInfo` type.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I managed to get this to work for `DataGridTextColumns`, but I also have `DataGridTemplateColumns` and need it to work for those too.

```
public string GetSelectedCellValue()
{
    DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[0];
    if (cellInfo == null) return null;

    DataGridBoundColumn column = cellInfo.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (column == null) return null;

    FrameworkElement element = new FrameworkElement() { DataContext = cellInfo.Item };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, TagProperty, column.Binding);

    return element.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, but I needed to specify the SortMemberPath of each column to be the property of `MyRowClass`.

```
public string GetSelectedCellValue()
{
    DataGridCellInfo cells = MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[0];

    YourRowClass item = cells.Item as YourRowClass;

    // specify the sort member path of the column to that YourRowClass property 
    string columnName = cells.Column.SortMemberPath; 

    if (item == null || columnName == null) return null;

    object result = item.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(item, null);

    if (result == null) return null;

    return result.ToString();
}
```